# If...else error (newbie, VHDL)

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

I'm having problems with getting this code to work:

```
if(s="00") then
    f3 <= x and not(y);
elsif(s="11") then 
    f3 <= not(y) xor x;
else 
    f3 <= x or y;
end if;
```

where:

```
f3 : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
x, y : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
s : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
```

Of course I can't really rely on compilation error messages, because they aren't specific about the error. Thanks in advance!

The whole code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity cw1 is
port(
    f0, f2 : out std_logic;
    f3 : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    a0, a1, a2, a3, a4 : in std_logic;
    x, y : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    s : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
);
end entity;

architecture A of cw1 is
    signal s1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal a : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
    s1 <= a0 & a1 & a2 & a3;
    a <= a0 & a1 &a2;

with a select
    f2 <= not(a4) when "000",
            a3 when "001"|"010"|"101"|"111",
            a4 or not(a3) when "011"|"100",
            '-' when "110",
            'X' when others;

if s="00" then
    f3 <= x and not(y);
elsif s="11" then 
    f3 <= not(y) xor x;
else 
    f3 <= x or y;
end if;

end A;
```

Comment: What _is_ the error? What do _you_ define as "working"?

Comment: The error is that it does not compile.
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at zA.vhd(36) near text "if";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
and
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at zA.vhd(36) near text "then";  expecting "<="

repeated a few times

Comment: The error is somewhere ahead of this code and the parser is getting out of sync. You can eliminate all the parentheses. They aren't needed around conditionals and the not operator isn't a function.

Comment: The error message IS specific about the error - "... or a concurrent statement". You are using if ... then in the concurrent region, whereas it should be used in a process. You could use conditional assignment form, `f3 <= x and not y when s = "00" else ...` here.

Comment: That's the problem @BrianDrummond - I have to use if-else for my classes to show that i can.

Comment: I have pasted the whole code. Does anyone know how to make this right?

Comment: Oh, sorry - I just understood what you had in mind @BrianDrummond.
It works within a process. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use if, you had to put it in a process:

```
process(s, x, y)
begin
  if(s="00") then
     f3 <= x and not(y);
  elsif(s="11") then 
     f3 <= not(y) xor x;
  else 
     f3 <= x or y;
  end if;
end process;
```